# Put Double `""` into a String

Tags: c#, string

I have this json

```
object tmp = new
            {
                name = Name,
                type = Type,
                parentId = ParentId,
                Location= string.Format("[\"{0}\"]" ,Location1)
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
```

This string is casuing the problem

```
string Location = string.Format("[\"{0}\"]" ,Location1)
```

The result is

```
{...,"Location":"[\"Location5201\"]"}
```

If i get rid of the `\`

Then the output is

```
{...,"Location":"[Location5201]"}
```

My desired output should be

```
{...,"Location":["Location5201"]}
```

How can i put `""` into the string above?

Comment: The thing is that `Location` is actually an array, but not a string. You don't need to form it with string yourself. You need to create an array: `Location = new[] { Location1 }`. You might want to spend more time on reading about JSON format and its serialization in C# before trying to achieve something with code in an initially incorrect way :)

Comment: When you say the result is, are you looking at it in the debugger window?

Comment: @RyanWilson I am running some tests the logs show me the results

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev That fixed my problem, consider adding an answer to this question :)

Comment: @WojtekT I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that `Location` property is actually an array of strings, but not a string.
You don't need to form it with string yourself. Instead, you need to declare it as an array:

```
Location = new[] { Location1 }
```

You might want to spend more time on reading about JSON format and its serialization in C# before trying to achieve something with code in an initially incorrect way.

Answer (score 3):

`["something"]` is JSON for "an array of one string":

```
Location = new []{ Location1 }
```

---

If `Location1` is not already of type `string`:

```
Location = new []{ Location1.ToString() }
```

or

```
Location = new []{ string.Format("{0}", Location1) }
```

Comment: @Esko OP said he needed quotes around the double value, so we'll need to coerce it into a string somehow - whether we use `string.Format()`, `ToString()` or cast the value in the initializer, is it that important?

Comment: @Esko ahh, I see now he wasn't actually talking about a `System.Double`, updated the answer